# Rails: A Volatile Data Structure To Store Temporary Data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, data-structures, volatile

I'm programming the backend of a mobile application and I've come across this problem, wondering whether I can use a rails tool or should I implement a new technology to my current system.

We have our user that is able to make a request, demanding to chat anyone who is around. However our system (the backend) has to collect this data and choose one of users who agree to chat randomly. But for that I want to keep all the ones that agree to chat in a list and pick one element randomly. But I would like to implement this in a volatile way so that when someone random selected all the other candidates will be gone.

Of course, those candidates could be easily stored in a table and later on could be deleted but I believe that there is a structure that I can use on demand and dump whenever I want. So what kind of data structure I should use to provide this efficiency?

Comment: Why when one is selected from list all others should be gone? Does that mean that they become not be chatted randomly?

Comment: I'm currently working in a stealth mode startup so the idea above is not exactly explained. However think it like after selection I want that list to be gone. I want to do it with using the efficient data structure that will be volatile, instead of querying database every single time.

Comment: In this case I'd use any serialised representation of semi-structured data: json, xml or Google protocol buffers. Note that if you want to query internal data in further delay you should duplicate this data in table columns.

Comment: Have you looked at memcached ? It would allow you to store a key in memory that would give you that list. All from one place. You can easily update the list (by overwriting it)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a volatile storage option for this, Redis is probably the best choice. Since data is stored in memory, it is fast. If you have many Rails instances running, they will still access the same central Redis server.

If you want to know a data-structure for this, I guess an array of user id is enough.